# Change from field in mailto link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, mailto

I'm using the mailto link in JavaScript to open my outlook email window which works fine:

```
parent.location='mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + "Test";
```

But the problem is I have multiple email accounts linked up to my outlook, so when I click on the mailto link it always uses the first email address in the From drop down menu in Outlook. But I want to use the second email address. Is there a way to select which email address to use in mailto?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't think that's possible. The mailto link doesn't talk to outlook per say, it just opens the default email client set on the machine and sets a subject, to, cc and message.